# Correct way to use git push -f

Tags: git

```
$ git branch

 master
*branch1
```

`$ git push -f`

And I over wrote origin/master with local stale master. What is the correct way to use `git push -f`  ?

Comment: This is a *very* broad question. What in particular about force pushing confuses you?

Comment: @Whymarrh I was looking for the best practices.

Comment: It would help if you could detail a scenario. The command's "best practices" (and even behavior) is dependent on the scenario in which it is used.

Comment: Essentially I wanted to push only branch1 to origin and nothing else. So @jmdeldin's answer is the right one. thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git push -f origin branch1
```

This will force push your branch1 and not master.